# concatenating two multidimensional arrays in numpy

Tags: python, numpy, concatenation

I have two arrays `A` and `B`,

```
>> np.shape(A)
>> (7, 6, 2)
>> np.shape(B)
>> (6,2)
```

Now, I want to concatenate the two arrays such that `A` is extended to `(8,6,2)` with `A[8] = B`

I tried `np.concatenate()`

```
>> np.concatenate((A,B),axis = 0)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-40-d614e94cfc50> in <module>()
----> 1 np.concatenate((A,B),axis = 0)

ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions
```

and `np.vstack()`

```
>> np.vstack((A,B))
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-41-7c091695f277> in <module>()
----> 1 np.vstack((A,B))
//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/shape_base.pyc in vstack(tup)
    228 
    229     """
--> 230     return _nx.concatenate([atleast_2d(_m) for _m in tup], 0)
    231 
    232 def hstack(tup):

ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions
```

Comment: Do [this](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.expand_dims.html) first before concat.

Comment: hey thanks, it worked :) first using `expand_dims` and then `np.concatanate`. btw what did you mean by use more expressive `np.vstack` then concat?

Comment: I didn't saw that you tried np.vstack too. In this case i would prefer vstack, because it needs no params and one can see whats happening immediatly. If you need to do this expand_dims stuff alot, you can also try the newaxis-approach (you only add indexing to B) mentioned in the docs. It's a bit shorter.

Comment: Your error message shows that `vstack` just hides some `concatenate` details.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Likely the simplest way is to use numpy [newaxis](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#numpy.newaxis) like this:

```
import numpy as np

A = np.zeros((7, 6, 2))
B = np.zeros((6,2))
C = np.concatenate((A,B[np.newaxis,:,:]),axis=0)
print(A.shape,B.shape,C.shape)
```

, which results in this:

```
(7, 6, 2) (6, 2) (8, 6, 2)
```

As @sascha mentioned you can use [vstack](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.vstack.html) (also see [hstack](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.hstack.html#numpy.hstack), [dstack](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.dstack.html#numpy.dstack)) to perform direct concatenation operations with an implicit axis (respectively `axis = 0`, `axis = 1`, `axis =2`):

```
D = np.vstack((A,B[np.newaxis,:,:]))
print(D.shape)
```

, result:

```
(8, 6, 2)
```