# Concatenating multi-dimensional arrays in Python

Tags: python, numpy

I have two arrays `C1` and `C2` with dimensions `(1, 2, 2)` . I want to append the arrays into a new array `C3`. The current and desired outputs are attached.

```
import numpy as np

arC1 = []
arC2 = []

C1=np.array([[[0, 1],[0,2]]])
arC1.append(C1)
C2=np.array([[[1, 1],[2,2]]])
arC2.append(C2)

C3=np.append(C1,C2)
```

The current output is

```
array([0, 1, 0, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2])
```

The desired output is

```
array([[[0, 1],[0,2]],[[1, 1],[2,2]]])

C3[0]=array([[0, 1],
       [0, 2]])

C3[1]=array([[1, 1],
       [2, 2]])
```

Comment: What's the problem?  Did you read the `append` docs? What's tbe desired `c3` shape and dtype?

Comment: `np.append` with `axis` is a simple call to `np.concatenate`.  Learn to use that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add a 2D matrix to another 3D matrix in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44808241/how-to-add-a-2d-matrix-to-another-3d-matrix-in-python)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [concatenating two multidimensional arrays in numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37186810/concatenating-two-multidimensional-arrays-in-numpy)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **axis** parameter of function **append**.

```
print(np.append(C1, C2))
"""
[0 1 0 2 1 1 2 2]
"""
print(np.append(C1, C2, axis=1))
"""
[[[0 1]
  [0 2]
  [1 1]
  [2 2]]]
"""
print(np.append(C1, C2, axis=0))
"""
[[[0 1]
  [0 2]]
 [[1 1]
  [2 2]]]
"""
```

I think **np.append(C1, C2, axis=0)** is what you want.